# SQL Adding Values based on the Hierarchy from Top to Bottom, with the bottom summing every from the top

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The concept of what I am doing is summing the total waiting time from a higher level unto a lower level. And get the total waiting time for that particular entity. Below is a picture of the Levels of the Hierarchy:

[image: 1]

My final output should be something like this.

[image: 2]

The Total Waiting Time is explained by this instance.
Total Waiting Times:

A = 1

B = 1 + 2 = 3

C = 1 + 3 = 4

D = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7

E = 1 + 2 + 5 =  8

F = 1 + 3 + 6 = 10

G = 1 + 3 + 7 = 10

I have an idea of joining the table with itself, but somehow it does not work, but somehow it doesn't show the expected results. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you! :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `recursive cte` as shown below:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, waitingTime AS TotalWaitingTime
    FROM waitingTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT w.*, TotalWaitingTime + w.waitingTime
    FROM waitingTime w
    JOIN cte ON w.ParentObject = cte.Object
)
SELECT
    object,
    ParentObject,
    waitingTime,
    MAX(TotalWaitingTime) TotalWaitingTime
FROM  cte
GROUP BY  object,ParentObject,waitingTime
GO
```

| object | ParentObject | waitingTime | TotalWaitingTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | 1 | 1 |
| B | A | 2 | 3 |
| C | A | 3 | 4 |
| D | B | 4 | 7 |
| E | B | 5 | 8 |
| F | C | 6 | 10 |
| G | C | 7 | 11 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4965ff5bd580dfd4e1977956efaab0ae)*

Comment: It's a good answer but I think you could format your SQL code so it is clearer.

Comment: @eshivana . . . I don't really like that formatting style either (way too much white space), but it is at least reasonable for upvoting.

Comment: . . It is documented in my book on SQL and Excel and I follow it pretty much on all my answers.  Basically, the clauses are left aligned, operators end lines, commas/semicolons never begin lines.  In your case, you have `from` and the tablename on different lines.